# SQL - Merge records by ID field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select statement where I get

```
ProductID  Gender Color Type     AgeRange
344842     Boys   NULL  NULL     NULL       
344842     NULL   Black NULL     NULL
344842     NULL   NULL  Leggings NULL   
344842     NULL   NULL  NULL     2 to 4 Years
```

I wish to get merged row like this

```
ProductID  Gender Color Type     AgeRange
344842     Boys   Black Leggings 2 to 4 Years
```

Comment: Can you just go Select ProductID, Max(Gender), max(Color) , max(Type), max(AgeRange) from Table1 where ProductID = 344842 group by ProductID

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
productid, max(Gender) as Gender, 
max(Color) as Color, max(Type) as Type, max(AgeRange) as AgeRange
from
table
group by 
productid
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
select productid, max(gender) as gender, max(color) as color, max(type) as Type, max(AgeRange) as AgeRange 
from yourtable group by ProductId
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select id,max(gender) gender, max(color) color, max(Type) Type, max(AgeRange) AgeRange from yourtable group by id
```